# phone connects to wifi hotspot (Ubuntu 17.10) but I can't browse

Tags: wireless, 17.10, hot-spot, netplan

I am getting an error when initiating the Wi-Fi hotspot that reads:

[Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot? It is not possible to access the internet through your wireless while the hotspot is active. Wi-Fi hotspots are usually used to share an additional internet connection over Wi-Fi.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4siX.png)

Do I need to add switchports, bruiges or routes to make it connect to the Inernet? I can see the Hotspot on my phone, but not connect to it.

This is a copy of my netplan 01-netcfg.yaml file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [76.80.54.221/29]
            gateway4: 76.80.54.217
            nameservers:
                addresses: [209.18.47.61,209.18.47.62]
        p2p1:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no     
            addresses: [192.168.1.129/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.100
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [192.168.1.127/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.100
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.1.100]
            access-points: 
                "free beer":
                    password: "something"
```

these are my output to:
sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: p2p1
       version: 0c
       serial: d8:cb:8a:a6:eb:a0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 83
       serial: 34:e6:ad:de:58:78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-19-generic firmware=17.608620.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:52 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:24:9b:16:e4:c0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a duplex=full ip=76.80.54.221 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
11: phy10: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0557:8021 ATEN International Co., Ltd CS1764A [CubiQ DVI KVMP Switch]
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 18f8:0f99  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 22b8:2e82 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: There is no config you can add specifically to make this work; the error is only telling you that you can't have the wireless connection be the one **sharing** the Internet connection, and the one **providing** it at the same time. For the rest, it looks like there's a bug in the AP support, probably in NetworkManager- - please file a bug: run the command "ubuntu-bug network-manager" when connected to the Internet, and the right logs and information will be added automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up trying to get the internal wifi of my system to work and got myself an external TP-LINK TL-WR902AC LAN to wifi router.

Not having had much experience setting up wifi with static/fix IP's **I learned that the broadcasting wifi IP (the one of the router) needed to match the phones IP!**

Now I can connect the phone via wifi to the Internet.